# clang-cl and CMAKE

Tags: c++, cmake, clang-cl

I tried to build simple program with CMAKE using clang on Windows, but CMAKE gave me error.

> CMake Error at C:/Program
> Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:859
> (message):   The Clang compiler tool
>
> ```
> "C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang++.exe"
> ```
>
> targets the MSVC ABI but has a GNU-like command-line interface.
> This is   not supported.  Use 'clang-cl' instead, e.g.  by setting
> 'CXX=clang-cl' in   the environment.

So I tried to set CXX=clang-cl enviromental variable
but it still does not work(same error message), although env variable is set

> echo %CXX%
>
> clang-cl

So my question is: is there a way to get CMAKE to work with clang-cl or clang on Windows.

Comment: Compilers are set either by `-D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=...` flag or CMake GUI.

Answer (score 2):

In cmake-gui you can choose clangcl on optional tool set -T.
It is very confuse because on Visual Studio it is called llvm (clang-cl) and not clangcl.
I tried many options and found the platform tool set folder in visual studio folder with the name clangcl. Using cmake-gui it worked fine for me, I think it should also work in the command line.